# Can I add copper wire led lights to existing 12V Landscape Light Transformer

Tags: led, low-voltage

I have an existing 12V low voltage landscape lights set on a transformer.

I have a 66ft copper wire LEDs that came with a 5V adaptor. Does this have to be plugged in separately; or can i connect it to the existing 12V wiring  with some sort of an adapter?

Comment: You would need to link the product so we can assess it.

Answer (score 2):

If "some sort of an adapter" is a 5V voltage regulator which can accept 12V or more input, *perhaps* yes. If not, no, and more may be needed if either one is AC, not DC.

You may (quite probably) also **overload** the 12V adapter if it's matched to the current string of lights such that adding more load would exceed its capacity.

Simpler and safer to just run the 5V adapter to a plug.